# Are functions called by a concurrent unordered map look-up thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, concurrency, thread-safety

Suppose I have the following code:

```
#include<concurrent_unordered_map.h>

struct firstStruct {
<irrelevant code>
}
struct secondStruct {
    void func(){ 
       <CRITICAL CODE>
    }
}
```

Let's suppose I have this:

```
concurrent_unordered_map<firstStruct,secondStruct> cmap = ...
```

and let's assume that that `cmap` has been populated, and that `firstStruct f` and `secondStruct s` are a `(key,value)` pair `(f,s)` that exist in `cmap`.

If I were to use the following code snippet

```
cmap[f].func();
```

Would the execution of the `<CRITICAL CODE>` in `func()` from `secondStruct s` be thread-safe?

Additionally, what would happen if I had the following code snippets, potentially being executed at the same time in different threads?

```
cmap[f].func();
```

and

```
SecondStruct s2 = ... ;
cmap[f] = s2;
```

If the `(key,value)` pair `(f,s)` was changed to `(f,s2)` by one thread, what would happen if another thread happens to be executing the `<CRITICAL CODE>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3425.html) for `concurrent_unordered_map`

> For serialized execution, the operations behave the same as their current STL counterparts. The only change is allowance for concurrency. Executing any of the following operations concurrently on a concurrent unordered container does not introduce a data race:
>
> ```
> get_allocator
> empty, size, max_size
> begin, end, cbegin, cend
> insert
> find, count, equal_range, operator[], at
> load_factor
> max_load_factor() 
> operator==, operator!=
> ```
>
> **assuming that the requisite operations on the key type (and mapped_type if applicable) are concurrency safe.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So, `operartor[]` is thread safe but the operation that you do with it's return value must also be thread safe to guarantee no data race happens.  That means the `<CRITICAL CODE>` in `func()` must be thread safe itself.  If it is not then something like

```
cmap[f].func();
SecondStruct s2 = ... ;
cmap[f] = s2;
```

Would also not be thread safe as the function would still be running while you assign a new object to the key.

Comment: Thank you very much! This cleared up a few doubts I had in few places in my code.


To work around this, I considered changing `cmap` to be this:


`concurrent_unordered_map<firstStruct,std::shared_ptr<secondStruct>> cmap = ...`



with func being call like so:


`std::shared_ptr<secondStruct> temp_ptr = cmap[f];
temp_ptr->func();`


would this be thread-safe? generally is there a better way to do this while maintaining thread safety and also ensuring speedy execution? I should point out at this point that speed is a big deal in my code.

Comment: @glopquestions That would be thread safe as long as no one does something like `*cmap[f] = s2;` (assign to the pointed to object instead of assign a new pointer).  If they assign a new pointer you'll be okay but if they change the underlying object on you then you are in the same boat.

Comment: I was thinking assigning using

`cmap[f] = std::make_shared<secondStruct>(s2);`

is this thread-safe?

(Just to clarify, mapping f to the same shared-pointer but changing what the shared-pointer points to (something different that I want) is dangerous), 
but 
(mapping f to a new shared-pointer and having this new shared-pointer point to whatever I want to is safe?)

Comment: @glopquestions Yes, that would be thread safe. `cmap[f]` would be reassigned to `std::make_shared<secondStruct>(s2)` but since `temp_ptr` exists then object you are calling the function on would still be alive.

Comment: @glopquestions Thread safety is a relative property.  Asking if a single operation is thread-safe is a category error.  Asking if two or more operations are relatively thread-safe makes sense.  You can even ask if two invocations of the same operation are thread safe to each other.  There are operations that are thread safe with the code in these comments; there are other operations that are not thread safe with the code in these comments.  If you ask the way you do, the other party has to read  your mind, and if they get it wrong they'll give the wrong answer and you'll be blissfully unaware.